# Clojure: map as function parameter

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to running some codes from the book "Web development with Clojure". There is a function which I can not understand:

```
(defn handle-upload [{:keys [filename] :as file}]
  (upload-page 
    (if (empty? filename)
      "please select a file to upload"
      (try 
        (upload-file (gallery-path) file)
        (save-thumbnail file)
        (db/add-image (session/get :user) filename)
        (image {:height "150px"}
          (str "/img/"
               (session/get :user)
               "/"
               thumb-prefix
               (url-encode filename)))
        (catch Exception ex 
          (str "error uploading file " (.getMessage ex)))))))
```

where

```
(defn upload-page [info]
    (layout/common
      [:h2 "Upload an image"]
      [:p info]
      (form-to {:enctype "multipart/form-data"}
               [:post "/upload"]
               (file-upload :file)
               (submit-button "upload"))))
```

What is the meaning of the parameter of the function `handle-upload`?

And after the changing from

`(defn handle-upload [{:keys [filename] :as file}]
...`

to

`(defn handle-upload [{:keys filename :as file}]
...`

I got an error message:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol, compiling:(picture_gallery/routes/upload.clj:32:1)`

Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`{:keys [filename] :as file}` means:

1. Take `:filename` key from passed argument and bind its value to `filename`
2. Leave the whole argument available as `file`

So if you pass:

```
{:filename "foo"
 :somethingelse "bar"}
```

As an argument, then `filename` in the function scope will be equal to `foo` and the `file` will be equal to the whole hash map.

References:

- [Special Forms](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--Binding%20Forms%20(Destructuring))

Comment: Also, you can do similar [de-structuring](http://blog.jayfields.com/2010/07/clojure-destructuring.html) with other collection types.