# Passing map parameters to a function in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have the following function:

```
(defn add-column-2
  [catalog columns]
  (println "Add-column-2")
  (update-in catalog ["streams" (column->tap-stream-id (:v1 columns))]
             add-column-to-stream
             (:v1 columns)
             (:v2 columns)))
```

In other words, I want that columns parameter as a map so that I can use the parameters v1 and v2 inside the function.

For that purpose, I am calling this function like:

```
(reduce add-column-2 empty-catalog all-columns)
```

Where `all-columns` is a map that contains *v1* and *v2* keys as you can see from this image:

[image: all-columns]

And empty-catalog is:

```
(def empty-catalog {"streams" {}})
```

However, when I am debugging, in the `add-column-2` function parameters:

- catalog: Comes as expected.
- columns: Only map entry with *v1* key is passing as you can see from the image below.

[image: add-column-2]

The question is, why the v2 key is not passing to the add-column-2 function? How can I pass whole map as a parameter?

P.S. During my investigation, I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27502643/clojure-map-as-function-parameter) however when I try like this, I am still unable to get that v2 key (it returns null).

Comment: The last argument of reduce is iterated over. Turning a map into a sequence becomes a sequence of map entries. If I had to guess, I think you want just `(add-column-2 empty-catalog all-columns)`. Also your subject claims some use of partial?

Comment: Hey @cfrick, sorry at first I was trying to use partial but then I changed that all-columns as a map since I need to pass three parameters to the add-column-2 function and I am using reduce. I fixed the title now.
Do you have any suggestion on using it with or without map/sequence?

Comment: `get-columns` is giving you a _map_ and then you try to reduce it. Either don't reduce, if `get-columns` is correct in giving you a map, or change `get-columns` to give a sequence, or put `[]` around. Another interpretation: is the value behind `v1`, what you actually want to reduce and the value of `v2` some constant, you wanted to provide?

Comment: Make sense; I was trying that "[]" approach before trying the map but I will try both of them together. Actually, both v1 and v2 is coming from different functions. I want to apply that method on each element of v1 sequence. v2 is just a method that returns result of a static query. I need to pass its value to `add-column-to-stream` function since one of the functions that called by that method requires that info.

Comment: I can run v2 in that leaf method but that time I need to pass my config file to that method and it seems not possible for the context of the code.